# Updating Variable with Current Row Value

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables, subquery, sql-server-2012

I am trying to perform a complex operation where I pull the sum for an entire column of data and subtract the running subtotal from the sum for each row.  I can do the component parts of Sum and Running Subtotal alone.  Used this for running subtotal:

```
sum(UsageMetric) over(order by Nested1.IDNumber) as RunningTotal
```

However, I get this error when trying to comine them:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used
>   as an expression.

So I rigged this up, and it returns the 'stand-alone' running subtotal for a given row:

```
declare @TargetNumber BIGINT
Set @TargetNumber=(select Nested1.IDNumber from TargetTable Nested1 where Nested1.IdNumber='1234567890' and (Extraneous Criteria Here))

select  sum(Usage.UsageMetric) 
from Table_Usage Usage, IDTable IDT
where IDT.IDNumber <= @TargetNumber
and (Extraneous Criteria Here)
```

But what I would really like to do is be able to remove the qualifier "Nested1.IDNumber='1234567890' and just perform this for each IDNumber in TargetTable.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you could do the following:

```
sum(UsageMetric) over () -
sum(UsageMetric) over (order by Nested1.IDNumber) as ...
```

Although simply reverting the order of rows in the OVER clause would yield the same results, I believe:

```
sum(UsageMetric) over (order by Nested1.IDNumber DESC) as ...
```

Comment: It always amazes me how the simplest code is the best code. Thanks so much.  This is much easier than what I was trying to do.  I still need to learn how to use variables properly in SQL, but this will get me where I need to go.